# Urgently Need Help, Can't boot ubuntu after shutdown didn't properly. [Stuck in black screen]

Tags: boot, shutdown

I Have a Ubuntu Server PC in My Office. last friday the pc boot properly. there's no problem. but then suddenly,this morning, the PC got shutdown didn't properly because the electricity problem in my office (the electricity got shut off then it turn on again) after that, i tried to turn on the pc, but it just stuck on the black screen with blinking underscore (bios work properly) i can't do anything. i've tried alt + f2, hold shift, but it doesn't work. what should i do?
if i try to boot the Ubuntu CD, then using the "nomodeset", would my data on the HDD erased? or it likes safe mode/startup repair on windows 7?
thanks. sorry i'm a newbie[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24Zsq.jpg)

Comment: not sure if that should count as a askUbuntu question, or not rather superuser one... not to mention pretty chaotic language, and the fact, that it has been probably already answered...

Answer (score 1):

If you boot the computer from Ubuntu CD (start live session, not installation process), you will then be able to mount your HDD. No data on the HDD will be erased just by starting live CD (it might have been damaged when you suffered power out though).